# Iterating over Hashes inside Arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have this Array of Hashes...

```
people = [
{:name => "Nick", :age => 28},
{:name => "John", :age => 29},
{:name => "Lisa", :age => 25},
{:name => "Brynn", :age => 24}
]
```

And I'd like to print out the name of each person using the following code:

```
people.map { |x| x[:name] }
names = []
people.each { |x| names << x[:name]}
```

This works, but I don't understand whats going on here (someone else solved this for me):

```
people.map { |x| x[:name] }
```

Can someone explain this to me? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line isn't doing anything, because you're throwing away its return value:

```
people.map { |x| x[:name] }
```

It also has nothing to do with the subsequent two lines.

If you want to produce the list of names, then use that line and throw away the last two, but store the array of names being returned:

```
names = people.map { |x| x[:name] }
```

That's all you need. That iterates over the array `people`, building a new array using the return value from the block. In essence, it does exactly what your last two lines do, but in one clean line.

These two snippets are functionally the same, but unrelated to each other. You need to choose one or the other:

```
names = people.map { |x| x[:name] }
```

*or*

```
names = []
people.each { |x| names << x[:name] }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is just the way you have to access the values of the hash's keys.

hash =  {name: "manu"}

In order to get manu from the hash you have to do

```
hash[:name]
```

Where name can be the key you want